# Extracting data between single quotes using sed or awk or grep when there are multiple single quoted data

Tags: sed

I have a sample text like this

> -message {This is a block with single quotes 'single_quoted_data'(domain 'this_is_the_first_domain(dov vcc:0.897
>   and vmm)') the next quoted data 'second_single_quoted_data'(domain
>   'this_is_the_second_domain(dov vcc:0.897 and vmm)') then some more
>   text}

here I want to extract:

`single_quoted_data` and `second_single_quoted_data`.

Please suggest an optimum way. I tried with `grep -o` followed by `sed` but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Prash:try:

```
awk -F"'" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /quoted_data/){print $i}}}'   Input_file
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you Prash, you could mark this/any solution as a correct answer if you want for helping others(for future references) keep learning !!

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It would be really  helpful for future visitors if you added some explanation why your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a suitable regexp:

```
grep -Eo "'[^'() ]+'"
```